# Writing subquery to display current paycheck date if one of 2 records is greater than zero

Tags: sql-server, subquery, case, ssms

I am working with a database table in which there are 2 records for each employee, one with a pay type of 'A' and another with a pay type of 'R'. If either of the 2 records has a current check gross amount of greater than zero, then I want to display the current check date, otherwise, return the hire date of that employee. Currently, it is only displaying the current check date for the single record in which the current check gross amount is greater than zero (if this exists). I have come up with a subquery inside a case statement but when I run this, it is returning the current check date for all records, including those that have a current check gross amount of zero. Can someone please help?

```
WHEN (SELECT MAX(CurrentCheckGross) 
    FROM EmployeeCheckDetails WHERE SSN = SSN) > 0 THEN @CheckDate
            ELSE FORMAT(ext.HireDate, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

The `@Checkdate` parameter represents the current check date and the SSN is the identifying column of the table.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful here.

Comment: This looks really scary to me. Why do you have SSN on every check row? That should be encrypted and stored at the employee level. It should not be stored anywhere else in the system. I sure hope my data isn't in that system.

Comment: So, rephrasing - you want the current check date for all 'A' and 'R' records where the amount is greater than zero; otherwise, you want the hire date.  So this will return either one or two rows: One hire date, one check date, or two check dates. Is this correct?